# Inexpensive nuclear reaction simulation tools

Tags: nuclear-physics, computational-physics, nuclear-engineering

I am interested in seeing if there are any simulation software programs for less than $50 that may be used to simulate how neutrons (energies between thermal and 15 MeV) interact with certain nuclei on a macroscopic level.

These "interactions" would include scattering (both inelastic and elastic), absorption, and fission.

My particular desire would be to simulate how neutrons being omni-directionally emitted would be scattered by a surrounding layer of liquid zinc-64. Thus, the intention would be to see how much energy was lost, what directions the neutrons would go, how far the majority (>90%) of neutrons would go before getting scattered, and where the majority of neutrons would end up (i.e. if there was any interaction with the initial omni-directional neutron source).

*This question was moved from the Computer Science Stack Exchange to its current location due to the recommendations provided by the forum's users. The hyper link to the previous location may be found [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/113546/inexpensive-nuclear-reaction-simulation-tools?noredirect=1#comment242070_113546)*

Comment: You mean like Geant (https://geant4.web.cern.ch/support/download)? Its free.

Comment: Geant is free, but it is not a trivial tool to use (it is a software framework to which you have to add non-trivial code). And while help is available, the people providing it rather expect you to be fairly independent in taking advantage of the documentation and exploring suggestions (similar to a particle physics graduate student). To get anything out of it you're going to have to raise the level of your game over that represented by your last few questions here.

Comment: @dmckee - indeed it is non-trivial. I know better than to try to use it myself and instead let the experts deal with it. Even then I've had them come back with statements along the line of 'you could pay me for the next year and I can't promise I'll get you a real answer'. Still, a large chunk of the answers seemingly desired come straight from the ENDF data they have been pointed to...

Comment: If Geant4 is a complicated set up, what would be some other solutions?

Comment: The other solution I've used is parsing the ENDFs myself and writing a toy Monte Carlo from scratch. Which of these is the right thing to do depends on how large and complex a project you have in mind. I wrote the toy MC to evaluate a tightly constrained group of $A(\alpha,n)$ reactions for use in a specialty calibration source. And that is near the break-even point for deploying the full framework.

Comment: And, understand that when you have many processes with widely varying cross sections, converging to a believable solution depends on getting enough statistics for the least likely event. That makes MC hard.